# creating a new ontology by OWL API

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I try to generate an ontology by means of OWL API in Eclipse neon. It doesn't have any error but could not be executed.

```
public class TestOntology {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://130.88.198.11/co-ode-files/ontologies/pizza.owl");
        try {
        OWLOntology ontology = man.loadOntology(ontologyIRI);
        System.out.println(ontology.getLogicalAxiomCount());
        } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

*my error*
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntologyCreationException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

class version 51 is Java 7. Are you running OWLAPI 4 on Java 6?

The minimal requirement for OWLAPI 4 is Java 7.

Comment: thanks. No, I use JRE 8u102 and JDK 8u102. Of course I am a new programmer in java.

Comment: Owlapi 4 is definitely compatible with Java 8 - it is what I use to compile and develop it. Not sure what else could be the issue. I would check in case you have multiple runtime environments on your machine.